# Get the values in PHP of three objects in Tripadvisor JSON API file

Tags: php, json, api, tripadvisor

Been struggling with this for too long now, so am kindly asking for your help.

How can I, using PHP, get the values of the text fields in the reviews of which there are three in this JSON file below.

Want to use a foreach loop for this, thanks for helping me out!

```
{
  "address_obj": {
    "street1": "Rustenburgerstreet 384",
    "street2": null,
    "city": "Amsterdam",
    "state": "North Holland Province",
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "postalcode": "1072 HG",
    "address_string": "Rustenburgerstreet 384, 1072 HG Amsterdam The Netherlands"
  },
  "percent_recommended": null,
  "latitude": "52.35162",
  "rating": "5.0",
  "attraction_types": [
    {
      "name": "concerts",
      "localized_name": "Concerts"
    },
    {
      "name": "blues bars",
      "localized_name": "Blues Bars"
    },
    {
      "name": "jazz bars",
      "localized_name": "Jazz Bars"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar/ clubs",
      "localized_name": "Bars & Clubs"
    }
  ],
  "wikipedia_info": null,
  "location_id": "3724036",
  "review_rating_count": {
    "1": "0",
    "2": "0",
    "3": "1",
    "4": "4",
    "5": "35"
  },
  "ranking_data": {
    "ranking_string": "#12 of 73 Theater &amp; Concerts in Amsterdam",
    "ranking_out_of": "73",
    "geo_location_id": "188590",
    "ranking": "12",
    "geo_location_name": "Amsterdam"
  },
  "photo_count": "35",
  "location_string": "Amsterdam, North Holland Province",
  "trip_types": [
    {
      "name": "business",
      "value": "0",
      "localized_name": "Business"
    },
    {
      "name": "couples",
      "value": "8",
      "localized_name": "Couples"
    },
    {
      "name": "solo",
      "value": "7",
      "localized_name": "Solo travel"
    },
    {
      "name": "family",
      "value": "0",
      "localized_name": "Family"
    },
    {
      "name": "friends",
      "value": "21",
      "localized_name": "Friends getaway"
    }
  ],
  "web_url": "Attraction_Review-g188590-d3724036-Reviews-m34757-CC_Music_Cafe-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "id": "353301385",
      "lang": "en",
      "location_id": "3724036",
      "published_date": "2016-03-06T05:20:19-0500",
      "rating": 5,
      "helpful_votes": "0",
      "rating_image_url": "img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/s5.0-34757-5.png",
      "url": "ShowUserReviews-g188590-d3724036-r353301385-CC_Music_Cafe-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html#review353301385",
      "trip_type": "Solo travel",
      "travel_date": "2016-02",
      "text": "I am a regular visitor of CC Muziekcafé Amsterdam but have felt at home from the very first time. What I like about CC is the atmosphere where great music and hospitality are mixed in the best way...",
      "user": {
        "username": "Yvon H",
        "user_location": {
          "name": "Groningen Province, The Netherlands",
          "id": "188570"
        }
      },
      "title": "A great place to hear live music and meet all sorts of interesting people, both local and traveling",
      "is_machine_translated": false
    },
    {
      "id": "351658487",
      "lang": "en",
      "location_id": "3724036",
      "published_date": "2016-02-28T11:13:12-0500",
      "rating": 5,
      "helpful_votes": "0",
      "rating_image_url": "img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/s5.0-34757-5.png",
      "url": "ShowUserReviews-g188590-d3724036-r351658487-CC_Music_Cafe-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html#review351658487",
      "trip_type": "Friends getaway",
      "travel_date": "2016-02",
      "text": "4th time we have been here, another great night at the music cafe, friendly people and a barman who knows how to just put enough swear words in to sound cool",
      "user": {
        "username": "Francois S",
        "user_location": {
          "name": "Cardiff, United Kingdom",
          "id": "186460"
        }
      },
      "title": "Jazz funk Jam session night Thursday",
      "is_machine_translated": false
    },
    {
      "id": "350605184",
      "lang": "en",
      "location_id": "3724036",
      "published_date": "2016-02-24T10:18:57-0500",
      "rating": 5,
      "helpful_votes": "1",
      "rating_image_url": "img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/s5.0-34757-5.png",
      "url": "ShowUserReviews-g188590-d3724036-r350605184-CC_Music_Cafe-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html#review350605184",
      "trip_type": "Couples",
      "travel_date": "2015-09",
      "text": "CC muziekcafe is a very cosy place with excellent live music and interaction with the musicians. What really makes the place is the owner Rene who knows a lot about music and now and then even sings...",
      "user": {
        "username": "ImagineNL",
        "user_location": {
          "name": "Schagen, The Netherlands",
          "id": "609049"
        }
      },
      "title": "Cupid",
      "is_machine_translated": false
    }
  ],
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you need a foreach to fetch the `reviews` element. Not sure if I understood your question correct, but did you want something like this:

```
$assoc_json = json_decode($your_json, true);
var_dump($assoc_json['reviews']);
```

The above turns your json into an associative array, and just access the `review` element.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear. I mean I want to loop trough the 3 reviews to store the values of the fields "text" and "rating", something like this:    foreach ($reviews as $review) {
     
     $review_text=$review->text;
                                        $review_rating=$review->rating;                                      }

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
<?php

$json = <<<EOF
{
  "address_obj": {
    "street1": "Rustenburgerstreet 384",
    "street2": null,
    "city": "Amsterdam",
    "state": "North Holland Province",
    "country": "The Netherlands",
    "postalcode": "1072 HG",
    "address_string": "Rustenburgerstreet 384, 1072 HG Amsterdam The Netherlands"
  },
  "percent_recommended": null,
  "latitude": "52.35162",
  "rating": "5.0",
  "attraction_types": [
    {
      "name": "concerts",
      "localized_name": "Concerts"
    },
    {
      "name": "blues bars",
      "localized_name": "Blues Bars"
    },
    {
      "name": "jazz bars",
      "localized_name": "Jazz Bars"
    },
    {
      "name": "bar/ clubs",
      "localized_name": "Bars & Clubs"
    }
  ],
  "wikipedia_info": null,
  "location_id": "3724036",
  "review_rating_count": {
    "1": "0",
    "2": "0",
    "3": "1",
    "4": "4",
    "5": "35"
  },
  "ranking_data": {
    "ranking_string": "#12 of 73 Theater &amp; Concerts in Amsterdam",
    "ranking_out_of": "73",
    "geo_location_id": "188590",
    "ranking": "12",
    "geo_location_name": "Amsterdam"
  },
  "photo_count": "35",
  "location_string": "Amsterdam, North Holland Province",
  "trip_types": [
    {
      "name": "business",
      "value": "0",
      "localized_name": "Business"
    },
    {
      "name": "couples",
      "value": "8",
      "localized_name": "Couples"
    },
    {
      "name": "solo",
      "value": "7",
      "localized_name": "Solo travel"
    },
    {
      "name": "family",
      "value": "0",
      "localized_name": "Family"
    },
    {
      "name": "friends",
      "value": "21",
      "localized_name": "Friends getaway"
    }
  ],
  "web_url": "Attraction_Review-g188590-d3724036-Reviews-m34757-CC_Music_Cafe-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html",
  "reviews": [
    {
      "id": "353301385",
      "lang": "en",
      "location_id": "3724036",
      "published_date": "2016-03-06T05:20:19-0500",
      "rating": 5,
      "helpful_votes": "0",
      "rating_image_url": "img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/s5.0-34757-5.png",
      "url": "ShowUserReviews-g188590-d3724036-r353301385-CC_Music_Cafe-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html#review353301385",
      "trip_type": "Solo travel",
      "travel_date": "2016-02",
      "text": "I am a regular visitor of CC Muziekcafé Amsterdam but have felt at home from the very first time. What I like about CC is the atmosphere where great music and hospitality are mixed in the best way...",
      "user": {
        "username": "Yvon H",
        "user_location": {
          "name": "Groningen Province, The Netherlands",
          "id": "188570"
        }
      },
      "title": "A great place to hear live music and meet all sorts of interesting people, both local and traveling",
      "is_machine_translated": false
    },
    {
      "id": "351658487",
      "lang": "en",
      "location_id": "3724036",
      "published_date": "2016-02-28T11:13:12-0500",
      "rating": 5,
      "helpful_votes": "0",
      "rating_image_url": "img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/s5.0-34757-5.png",
      "url": "ShowUserReviews-g188590-d3724036-r351658487-CC_Music_Cafe-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html#review351658487",
      "trip_type": "Friends getaway",
      "travel_date": "2016-02",
      "text": "4th time we have been here, another great night at the music cafe, friendly people and a barman who knows how to just put enough swear words in to sound cool",
      "user": {
        "username": "Francois S",
        "user_location": {
          "name": "Cardiff, United Kingdom",
          "id": "186460"
        }
      },
      "title": "Jazz funk Jam session night Thursday",
      "is_machine_translated": false
    },
    {
      "id": "350605184",
      "lang": "en",
      "location_id": "3724036",
      "published_date": "2016-02-24T10:18:57-0500",
      "rating": 5,
      "helpful_votes": "1",
      "rating_image_url": "img/cdsi/img2/ratings/traveler/s5.0-34757-5.png",
      "url": "ShowUserReviews-g188590-d3724036-r350605184-CC_Music_Cafe-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html#review350605184",
      "trip_type": "Couples",
      "travel_date": "2015-09",
      "text": "CC muziekcafe is a very cosy place with excellent live music and interaction with the musicians. What really makes the place is the owner Rene who knows a lot about music and now and then even sings...",
      "user": {
        "username": "ImagineNL",
        "user_location": {
          "name": "Schagen, The Netherlands",
          "id": "609049"
        }
      },
      "title": "Cupid",
      "is_machine_translated": false
    }
  ]
}
EOF;

$array = json_decode($json, true);
$texts = array_map(
    function($item) {
        return $item['text'];
    }, $array['reviews']
);
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it working now with the array_map() function!

Answer (score 0):

A simple, naive approach would be:

```php
//Loads your json file 'tripadvisor' into jsonString
$jsonString = file_get_contents("/tripadvisor.json");
//Turns your string into an associative array
$tripJsonAssoc = json_decode($jsonString, true);
//Iterate through each review and store it in result
$result = array();
foreach($tripJsonAssoc['reviews'] as $review) {
    $result[] = array('text' => $review['text'],
                      'rating' => $review['rating']);
}
//Do what you need to do with result
//...
```

Or you can just do your own stuff inside the foreach loop.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35903442/4257747) gives you another way (more elegant) to create the 'result' array, but since you asked for a 'foreach', I thought I would add my 5 cents.